# Compare two BCrypt encrypted hashes (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, devise, bcrypt

I have two encrypted hashes that I want to compare and see if they are the same original plain text passwords, is that possible?

I control both databases (one is staging, the other production). My use case is that I want to have it so that when a user logs into production, it will check the staging environment and attempt to log them into by comparing the encrypted password hash from each database. The main reason is I might have to do this after the initially login (won't have the plain text password at that point) and would like to avoid passing the plain text over HTTPS.

The problem that I'm figuring out now is that the same plain text password will have a different encrypted output. I'm using Devise in Rails btw if that helps.

**Production**

"welcome" = `"$2a$10$vl0ydq1FXBbJr4Fi46xgcebjfXcvTn.gDEPWkcEI92eMQHom1s20C"`

**Staging**

"welcome" = `"$2a$10$qJXnbMhDMsfAFXlUAXlRsOH1oQFIYg4GkW6.zlFMgqoX24xKhsDUm"`

Comment: I'm confused about whether you can be in production and development at the same time, and even if you could be why you would want to? If you're deployed you have access to only the production db, afaik.  You are correct that the passwords will never match. There's a way to suppress the password in the logs, if that is what you're wanting to protect. How about not creating the user until he has supplied a password? That password will be seen only by him, as Devise will encrypt it on its way to the server.

Comment: Yeah production and staging are on two separate servers and separate IP addresses. I only have access to the plain text password at the moment the user signs in so the workaround I have now is to send that password over HTTP to sign into staging and if it passes send back a Devise `:authentication_token` and redirect with `?token=xxx` appended to the url. I would much prefer to compare two encrypted passwords if possible.